# Putting three acquired values from for loops into DataFrame / Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The idea is simple, you open a text file, you read it, you find how many times did the letters repeated itself and then estimate the percentage of each letter in text.

```
fileName = input("Enter file Name: ")
with open(fileName) as f:
    text = f.read()
print(text)

def count_char(text, char):
    count=0
    for c in text:
        if c == char:
            count+=1
    return count

for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    percentage = 100 * count_char(text, char) / len(text)
    print("\n letter: {0} is taking {1}% of the text and that is {2}".format(char, round(percentage,2), count_char(text, char)))
```

I did manage to do this but I can't put these values into dataframe to look more user friendly.

Also, I want to make an if-else statement if the user entered a file that does not exist ("Error 404 File Not Found!") message.

Answer (score 1):

Once you read in the file such that the contents are a string in the name `text`.  You can pass that to the `pandas.value_counts` function to give you the counts of each character.  In order to filter out only letters, I use the `filter` function and pass the `str.isalpha` as a predicate to determine the truthfulness for each character.

### `pandas.value_counts`

Your code should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

fileName = input("Enter file Name: ")
if os.path.exists(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        text = f.read()
else:
    print(("Error 404 File Not Found!")

counts = pd.value_counts([*filter(str.isalpha, text)]) / len(text)
print(counts)

a    0.064935
f    0.058442
q    0.051948
d    0.045455
r    0.045455
j    0.038961
e    0.032468
l    0.032468
k    0.032468
s    0.032468
t    0.032468
u    0.032468
i    0.032468
p    0.025974
w    0.025974
h    0.025974
g    0.019481
o    0.019481
y    0.012987
n    0.012987
T    0.006494
Q    0.006494
R    0.006494
dtype: float64
```

---

### Setup

```
text = """
a;sdlkfja;sldkfja
spogkia
;dlkfq
;welrfuq[3094t8urq34TRQaaj]
aksdfjpaoi43urpq9384t983456tuyweirghnwehrg
q34haed89fy9q9384uithnjlfasdf;q3p[er]q34t9rwiofdj"""
```

Comment: Please explain more I don't quite understand..and how this will apply to my code?

Comment: @piRSquared has showed you how you can take a string of text and enter it into a dataframe where you can perform ```pandas``` operations on it. How does this fail to answer your question? Can you be more specific in what else you need help with?

Comment: ohhh i get it now, i'm sorry i was a little confused, i think that the best part is @payne solved with just a line of code, thanks so much

Comment: @campellcl i just need now the if-else statements as i mentioned, thanks in advance.